# Parse txt file using perl

Tags: perl

I would like to parse a file containing data as below:

```
05\/26\/2013 06:09:47 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=radash@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:47 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolched@abc.com
05\/26\/2013 06:09:48 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=rad-ash2s@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:48 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolchedssd@abc.com
05\/26\/2013 06:09:49 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.43 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=sjhsjdh@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:49 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=kjsdsdjhjsh@abc.com
```

and get:

```
05/26/2013 06:09:49  and uid=radash@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com 
05/26/2013 06:09:48  and uid=rad-ash2s@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com
```

I tried split('-') but it does not work split('-') because as you can see :
Some lines like the second one above has: rad-ash2s@abc.com   ( a '-' ) in between.
Also some times, there are '-' in other part of data too.

Please help.

Comment: how about `split / - /` with spaces around the hyphen?

Comment: Do the backslashes actually exist in the data?

Comment: @amon I'll try.  Presently i'm using split("-",$line), not how shall i change it to have space?

Comment: @Borodin Yes , they exist in the data

Comment: On the second line after "and get", you had backslash in front of `,ou` and `,o`, is that a typo?

Comment: @doubleDown sorry yes edited it

Answer (score 1):

You maybe better off using a regular expression. With a regular expression, I can quickly grab the part of the string I want with `(...)`. See the Perldoc on [Regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) to see what the various regular expression meta-characters mean.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use 5.12.0;
use warnings;
use autodie;

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/\\//g;   #Remove all backslashes
    $line =~ /^(.+?) -.+?(uid=\S+)/;
    my $date = $1;
    my $uid = $2;
    say qq($date and $uid);
}

__DATA__
05\/26\/2013 06:09:47 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=radash@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:47 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolched@abc.com
05\/26\/2013 06:09:48 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.44 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=rad-ash2s@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:48 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=bolchedssd@abc.com
05\/26\/2013 06:09:49 \-0700 - AUTHN_SUCCESS - GET - ddsbcggio_ac  - 200.12.33.43 - abcweb.eegeserv.com\/abcweb\/abcwebInitialize.do?PORT=SPQ  - uid=sjhsjdh@abc.com\,ou=People\,o=zeb.com - 06:09:49 - http - uizweb_zam -  - 2uid=kjsdsdjhjsh@abc.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This program does what you ask. It looks like the field separator is `' - '`, i.e. a hyphen with a space either side, giving a blank penultimate field (the eleventh).

This program expects the name of the input file as a parameter on the command line.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<>) {
  chomp;
  tr/\\//d;
  my @fields = split /\x20-\x20/;
  printf "%s and %s\n", @fields[0,6];
}
```

With your own data, this produces

```
05/26/2013 06:09:47 -0700 and uid=radash@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com
05/26/2013 06:09:48 -0700 and uid=radash2s@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com
05/26/2013 06:09:49 -0700 and uid=sjhsjdh@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com
```

Comment: What if the file has:
uid=rad - ash2s@abc.com,ou=People,o=zeb.com.  Will this work?

Comment: No. You are asking too much. Is that likely? Or even possible?

Comment: If they are valid email addresses then they cannot contain whitespace.

Comment: Yes, i have something like uid=rad-ash2s@abc.com,ou=Peo - ple,o=zeb.com. Please note ou=Peo - ple

Comment: @david: Then please describe how to distinguish between " - " as a separator and the same thing within a field.